# OptaPlanner Solution's score not matches the score given by `ScoreManager::explainScore`

Tags: optaplanner, constraint-programming

To be honest, I have a complicated model, and there's a chance there's an error in my OptaPlanner model.

I'm not sure that the following is possible and normal, or there's some error somewhere in my mapping, and I should create an MCVE based on my entities.

TLDR:

I have the following Kotlin code somewhere in my project:

```kotlin
        val solverJob = solverManager.solveAndListen(problem.id, problemMap::get) {
            val hardScore = it.score!!.hardScore
            if (scoreManager.explainScore(it).score.hardScore != hardScore) {
                throw IllegalStateException()
            }
            onBetterSolutionFoundCallback(mapSolutionToFrontendObject(it))
        }
```

It's pretty easy, it gives a problem to OptaPlanner, and calls a callback when a better solution is found. The trick here is that it double-checks whether the solution is feasible or not.

Aaaaand, sometimes the `IllegalStateException` is thrown. The `scoreManager.explainScore(it).score` reports, that there's one hard constraint violation, while the `solution.score` says there's no hard constraint violation.

The tricky part is that `solution.score` is updated after the `scoreManager.explainScore` method is called.

I've taken a look at the solution, and the `ScoreManager` is correct: there's one hard constraint violation in the solution. But everything reports, that it's a feasible solution until I call the `scoreManager.explainScore` method.

The OptaPlanner finds 2 correct solutions before this exception is thrown in my case, so there are feasible solutions, but OptaPlanner replaces them with a non-feasible one.

Is it correct behavior?

Or is there some error in my domain model?

Or it's a bug in OptaPlanner, and I should create a bugreport based on this?

I'm using Quarkus 1.11.1.Final, and OptaPlanner 8.1.0.Final.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporarly add this in your application.properties to fail faster with a clearer error message pointing toward the cause:

```
# To detect common bugs in your code
quarkus.optaplanner.solver.environment-mode=FULL_ASSERT
```

Give it more time, because FULL_ASSERT heavily slows things down. See optaplanner docs section "environment mode" to understand what it does.

Comment: Hi @Geoffrey, I have the following solverConfig in XML: https://pastebin.com/8qQ7Jdm2, and as far as I understand it sets the envMode to FULL_ASSERT, but the score mismatch happens in this case too. I'm trying to modify the VRP with the 2 following addons: the vehicles needs to have either 1 or 2 drivers; and the vehicles needs to go back to the garages after a while.

Comment: Check you info log - it will state if FULL_ASSERT is active. So exceptions being thrown if you let it solve for a long time with FULL_ASSERT on?

Comment: Okay, thanks, the FULL_ASSERT wasn't read from the XML config, I needed to add it to the `application.propertes` file as well. Thanks, I'll let it run for a while, and I'll come back.

Comment: Thanks @Geoffrey, this Exception is thrown: https://pastebin.com/v3hpanjV . So as far as I understand my constraints are not good, I'll check them. One question though: I have a CHAINED PlanningVariable (named `previousTask`).  Is it correct to check multiple steps _back_ on this `previousTask` variable? So if i want to penalize something between a `Task`, and the `previousTask.previousTask.previousTask` in a constraint?